# Getting Typescript error in useMutation (react-query)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-query

I want to create subscribe form page and I use `next js`, `react-query`, `typescript`. I can not configurate my API request in `typescript`.

My form component

```
'use client';
import React, { FormEvent, useState } from 'react';

import { useEmailSubscription } from 'src/api/email-subscription/mutations';

const SubscribeForm = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const { mutate } = useEmailSubscription();

  const _onSubmit = (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    mutate(email);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={_onSubmit}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label id="email">Stay tuned for an awesome experience!</label>
        <input
          type="email"
          id="email"
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="email@mail.com"
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default SubscribeForm;
```

My first error

```
mutate(email) // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'
```

My request

```
export const useEmailSubscription = () => {
  return useMutation((email: string) => axiosOpen.post('/email-subscriptions', { email }));
};
```

My second error

```
Type (email: string)=> Promise <AxiosResponse <any, any>> has no properties in common with type 'UseMutationOptions<unknown, Error, void, unknown'
```

I don't know how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The error says that you are passing a function where `MutationOptions` would be expected. I assume you are using v5 of React Query, where the only available syntax is to pass an options object to `useQuery` and `useMutation`. So you need:

```
export const useEmailSubscription = () => {
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: (email: string) => axiosOpen.post('/email-subscriptions', { email })
  })
};
```

calling `mutate(email)` is correct and the error should go away after that.

Answer (score 0):

**First Error: `mutate(email)`**

Your `mutate` function is expecting a parameter of type `void` , but you are passing a string (`email`). This discrepancy is likely due to how you defined your mutation. In your `useEmailSubscription` hook, you need to properly type the mutation function.

**Second Error: Type Mismatch with `useMutation`**

You need to ensure that the type you specify in useMutation aligns with the function you're passing.

Change your mutation hook like this:

```
export const useEmailSubscription = () => {
  return useMutation<void, Error, string>((email) => axiosOpen.post('/email-subscriptions', { email }));
};
```

The form component should work as is, with the mutate function correctly accepting a string argument